# C - How do I return a pointer value to main?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, stack, allocation

I have this homework that asks me to make a stack using dynamic allocation and add some different functions in it. Now, usually I would use the head pointer as global variable and make things easier for me, but the homework demands that I give the head pointer to the function as an argument, so I made it local variable in main. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node;

void push(int val, node *head) {
    node* temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* current = head;
    temp->val = val;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
}

void print(node *head) {
    node* current = head;
    if (current->next != NULL) {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            printf("%d", current->val);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("%d", current->val);
    }
}

int main() {
    node * head = NULL;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(n, head);
    print(head);
    push(n, head);
    print(head);
    push(n, head);
    print(head);
}
```

I get a segmentation fault error at the first print(head) function that says `print(head = 0x0)`, which made me believe that head does not update when it returns in main. I used a `printf()` for head after the first push function and I was right, head returns `0`. Question is: How do I return the updated head in the function?

Comment: Read about passing arguments by value vs. by reference

Comment: possible duplicate of [struct of linked list, passing paramters - c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352313/struct-of-linked-list-passing-paramters-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either declare your function like

```
void push(int val, node **head)
```

then pass a reference of your head and modify it

or

```
node *push(int val, node *head)
```

and return the new head.